# How to check total count of values using Laravel

Tags: laravel-4, count

I have a table 'student_attendence'

I want like this

```
RollNo  StudentName  02 13  14  15  16  17  20  Total Presents  Total Absents
  28     Gokul        p  p   p  p   a   p   p       6                 1
  31     Goku         p p   p   a   p   p   p       6                 1
  32     Gok          p p   p   p   p   a   a       5                 2
```

I want take total count of present(p) and absent(a) of each student.

My controller code is:

```
$attendence_tbl = WysAttendancename::where('cls_id',$id)->first();
$wys_attendence_table = $attendence_tbl->attendance_name;
$attendance = DB::table($wys_attendence_table)
              ->where('amonth',$amonth)
              ->where('ayear',$ayear) 
              ->groupBy('adate')
              ->get();
$stud_attend = DB::table($wys_attendence_table)
               ->where('amonth',$amonth)
               ->where('ayear',$ayear) 
               ->get();
```

and my view.blade php is

```
 @foreach($students as $student)                  
                  @if($student->studcls == $id)
                  <tr> 
                    <td>{{$student->id}}</td>
                    <td>{{$student->studname}}</td>
                  @foreach($stud_attend as $stud_attends)
                  @if($student->id == $stud_attends->studid)  
                  @if($stud_attends->attendence == 1)
                  <td><font color="green" size="3">p</font></td>
                  @elseif($stud_attends->attendence == 0)
                  <td><font color="red" size="3">a</font></td>   
                  @endif
                  @endif                 
                  @endforeach
                  <td>{{$presentsCountQuery}}</td>
                  <td>{{$absentsCountQuery}}</td>
                  </tr>          
                  @endif                 
                  @endforeach
```

and also I am adding this code

```
foreach($students as $student){
            $cunt = DB::table($wys_attendence_table)
                 ->where('studid',$student->id)
                 ->where('amonth',$amonth)
                 ->where('ayear',$ayear) 
                 ->where('attendence','=',1)
                 ->count();
            var_dump($cunt);      
        }
```

in to my controller page to check total count of presents and absent.

iam take var_dump  got he answer  int(6) int(6) int(5)

But i can't display on view page

How to check total count of present(attendence = 1) and total count of absent(attendence =0)of each student in my controller page and also how to display values to view page?

This is my table wys_attendence:

```
id   studid  adate  amonth  ayear  acls_id  attendence      
1    28      02     07      2015   10       1     
2    31      02     07      2015   10       0  
4    32      02     07      2015   10       1   
5    28      30     07      2015   10       0 
6    31      30     07      2015   10       1   
7    32      30     07      2015   10       1   
9    28      31     07      2015   10       1   
10   31      31     07      2015   10       1   
11   32      31     07      2015   10       1   
13   28      06     08      2015   10       1   
14   31      06     08      2015   10       0   
15   32      06     08      2015   10       1   
17   28      07     08      2015   10       0   
18   31      07     08      2015   10       1   
19   32      07     08      2015   10       1   
21   28      08     08      2015   10       1   
22   31      08     08      2015   10       1   
23   32      08     08      2015   10       0   
24   28      12     08      2015   10       1   
25   31      12     08      2015   10       1   
26   32      12     08      2015   10       0
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this @cnbwd:

```
  $attendance = WysAttendancename::select('id', 'studid', 'adate', 'amonth','ayear', 'acls_id','attendence',
        DB::raw('(SELECT count(attendence) from your_db WHERE attendence = 1) as count_attendence' ))
        ->where('amonth',$amonth)
        ->where('ayear',$ayear)
        ->groupBy('adate')
        ->get();
```

Comment: sir iam using this code ..i got an error. SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column '(DB::raw('count('attendence') WHERE attendence = 1 '))' in 'field list' (SQL: select `(DB::raw('count('attendence') WHERE attendence = 1 '))` from `wys_8-1_att` where `amonth` = 07 and `ayear` = 2015)

Comment: Inside the count what is the column would you want to count.

Comment: column name is  attendence. i want total count of each student attendence separetly  . where attendence =1 .i want  like above box.

Comment: sorry i dont understand  ->select("(DB::raw('count('column_you_want_to_count') WHERE attendancge = 1 '))")   how to write  this  'column_you_want_to_count' ?

Comment: Can you show me the tables and columns of your database sir?

Comment: yes iam using this code foreach($students as $student){
            $cunt = DB::table($wys_attendence_table)
                 ->where('studid',$student->id)
                 ->where('amonth',$amonth)
                 ->where('ayear',$ayear) 
                 ->where('attendence','=',1)
                 ->count();
            var_dump($cunt);      
        }  and iam try to var_dump($cunt) i got correct answer ,but i don't know how to display in my view page. my vie.blade.php code is above.

Comment: A note to your previous answer... DB::raw is not a string. Do not take it beatween quotes. Only the parameter of DB::raw() is a string.

Comment: Ahh. Yes. I forgot to remove that.

Comment: sir iam using this code ....$attendance = WysAttendancename::select('(all_your_columns)',
            DB::raw('SELECT count(attendence) from your_db WHERE attendence = 1'))
            ->where('amonth',$amonth)
            ->where('ayear',$ayear)
            ->groupBy('adate')
            ->get(); ..but got another error

Comment: lluminate \ Database \ QueryException (42000)

SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'SELECT count(attendence) from $wys_attendence_table WHERE attendence = 1 from `w' at line 1 (SQL: select *, SELECT count(attendence) from $wys_attendence_table WHERE attendence = 1 from `wys_attendancenames` where `amonth` = 07 and `ayear` = 2015 group by `adate`)  ..this is my error

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$attendance = DB::table($wys_attendence_table)
->select(DB::raw('count(attendence) as count_attendance'))
->where('amonth',$amonth)
->where('ayear',$ayear)
->groupBy('adate')
->get();
```

Edit

You can make one query from the two, and use it in one foreach.
Something like this:

```
$countQuery = DB::table($wys_attendence_table)
    ->select(DB::raw('studid, COUNT(*) AS counter'))
    ->groupBy('studid')
    ->toSql();

$stud_attend = DB::table($wys_attendence_table . ' AS table')
    ->leftJoin(DB::raw('(' . $countQuery . ') AS counter_table'), 'table.studid', '=', 'counter_table.studid')
    ->where('amonth',$amonth)
    ->where('ayear',$ayear)
    ->groupBy('adate')
    ->get();
```

Edit2:

```
$presentsCountQuery = DB::table($wys_attendence_table)
    ->select(DB::raw('studid, COUNT(*) AS presents_counter'))
    ->whereRaw('attendence = 1')
    ->groupBy('studid')
    ->toSql();

$absentsCountQuery = DB::table($wys_attendence_table)
    ->select(DB::raw('studid, COUNT(*) AS absents_counter'))
    ->whereRaw('attendence = 0')
    ->groupBy('studid')
    ->toSql();

$stud_attend = DB::table($wys_attendence_table . ' AS table')
    ->leftJoin(DB::raw('(' . $presentsCountQuery . ') AS presents_counter_table'), 'table.studid', '=', 'presents_counter_table.studid')
    ->leftJoin(DB::raw('(' . $absentsCountQuery . ') AS absents_counter_table'), 'table.studid', '=', 'absents_counter_table.studid')
    ->where('amonth',$amonth)
    ->where('ayear',$ayear)
    ->groupBy('adate')
    ->get();
```

Edit3:

Full code:

```
$attendance = DB::table($wys_attendence_table)
            ->whereRaw('amonth = "'.$amonth.'"')
            ->whereRaw('ayear = "'.$ayear.'"')
            ->groupBy('adate')
            ->get();

$presentsCountQuery = DB::table($wys_attendence_table)
            ->select(DB::raw('studid, COUNT(*) AS presents_counter'))
            ->whereRaw('amonth = "'.$amonth.'"')
            ->whereRaw('ayear = "'.$ayear.'"')
            ->whereRaw('attendence = 1')
            ->groupBy('studid')
            ->toSql();

$absentsCountQuery = DB::table($wys_attendence_table)
            ->select(DB::raw('studid, COUNT(*) AS absents_counter'))
            ->whereRaw('amonth = "'.$amonth.'"')
            ->whereRaw('ayear = "'.$ayear.'"')
            ->whereRaw('attendence = 0')
            ->groupBy('studid')
            ->toSql();

$stud_attend = DB::table($wys_attendence_table . ' as table')
            ->leftJoin(DB::raw('(' . $presentsCountQuery . ') AS presents_counter_table'), 'table.studid', '=', 'presents_counter_table.studid')
            ->leftJoin(DB::raw('(' . $absentsCountQuery . ') AS absents_counter_table'), 'table.studid', '=', 'absents_counter_table.studid')
            ->where('table.amonth',$amonth)
            ->where('table.ayear',$ayear)
            ->groupBy('table.studid')
            ->get();
var_dump($stud_attend);
```

Comment: What is the problem? I tested my solution and it works fine. What you experience?

Comment: Try to copy and paste full of my code and please test it. Do not just edit some part of yours. It has to work. I am sure you make some mistake. For example the counter queries should be toSql() not count(), in the counter queries you have to use whereRaw not where. The whereRaw get only one string not a string and an int. So if you do not understand what is why do not edit, just copy and paste. Than think after. Try to understand the error message. And if something is not good PLEASE TELL US. Do not just that "it is not working." Thanks.

Comment: sir. iam Try to copy and paste full of my code and test it. igot only the student name not display values of presents and absents of corresponding dates     and total no.present below select studid, COUNT(*) AS presents_counter from `wys_8-1_att` where amonth = "07" and ayear = "2015" and attendence = 1 group by `studid`  total no.absents below select studid, COUNT(*) AS absents_counter from `wys_8-1_att` where amonth = "07" and ayear = "2015" and attendence = 0 group by `studid`....the sql query will be print on my view page..

Comment: So iam edit my code with the help of your code ..i got the correct present and absent values of corresponding date.. and count of present and absents of last student.